# How do I restore my entire Trash can to Inbox in Gmail, not just one page at a time?

Tags: gmail

Gmail erroneously moved *all* 16,000 of my messages in *all* folders to Trash. Now I have to restore them, at least to my Inbox, if nothing else, where most messages resided. However, I can only select messages one page at a time. At 50 messages per page, this could take a looong time. Is there a way to move all contents of the Trash can at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just found out how to do this, thank God. When you **select all messages in a page**, a **new line pops up** just above the topmost message; in that line, there is an underlined **"select all 16,000 messages"**. Click that, and then you can perform an operation (such as *move*) to all your messages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your trash folder. In the upper right hand corner, click the checkbox, then select all.

Then, go to the *Move to* drop down and move where it makes sense.

Screen shot below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Wade, thanks for your answer. The problem was that, this way, you can only move one page of your Trash at a time, which would have taken a long time, what with 16,000 messages in there. But I found out (as mentioned above) that the option to select all messages in the Trash can (as opposed to all in page) appears once you select "all". I found the solution as I was still typing the question, so I immediately posted the answer to my own question as well. Oh, and welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score -2):

Click the box menu in the top left corner, and select all (or you could select messages individually).

After selecting the message(s) you want to move, right click in the middle of the screen or where the messages are located.  A drop menu will appear, from there select "move to inbox".